# How to remove images from my plugin page in WP Directory?

Tags: plugin-development, svn

I can't understand why, but I can't rid of old (unnecessary) screenshots of [my plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mightyforms) in WP Directory.

I've removed `assets` folder from each version in `tags`, removed `assets` folder from `trunk`, made commit, but on the plugin's page on WP Directory those images still here.

If I hover cursor over some unnecessary image - I'll see hash of commit which firstly contain this image.
[How to get rid of this image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwtbC.png)

Comment: This could be due to caching in the wp.org plugin directory

Comment: Hm, thank for suggestion. Do you know, how much time need to wait for expiring a cache?

Comment: Solution: Need to use `svn delete ` command to delete files, and then commit changes.
https://prnt.sc/v0lzb2

Comment: @СашкоЛисий Thats great. I thought you had done that trivial thing. But you should now answer your own question as you found the solution too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use `svn delete` command to delete files, and then commit the changes.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/v0lzb2